# Data binding not updating when $scope variable changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding

I have a login form who's visibility is bound to a variable. I have a link in the form that changes text depending on whether the user is logging in or registering. When the form is exited, I reset the form to `isOnLoginForm` which updates the registration text. The problem is, the scope variable changes but the registration text doesn't - it updates when clicking the registration button, but not when hiding the form.

Here is the controller:

```
angular.module('DataStructureVisualizer').
controller("RegLoginController", function($scope, $rootScope) {

  //Show / hide login form
  $scope.toggleRegLoginForm = function() {
    $rootScope.RegLoginForm.showForm = ! $rootScope.RegLoginForm.showForm;

    if($rootScope.RegLoginForm.showForm == true) {
      $rootScope.RegLoginForm.isOnLoginForm = true;
    }

    updateRegistrationText();
  }

  $scope.isRegLoginFormShown = function() {
    return $rootScope.RegLoginForm.showForm;
  }

  //Updating form to be registration
  updateRegistrationText();

  function updateRegistrationText() {
    $scope.registrationText = $rootScope.RegLoginForm.isOnLoginForm ? 'Need to create an account?' : 'test';    
    console.log($scope.registrationText);
  }

  $scope.switchToRegistration = function() {
    $rootScope.RegLoginForm.isOnLoginForm = false;
    updateRegistrationText();
  }
});
```

And here is the view:

```
<div id="RegLoginBlackout" ng-controller="RegLoginController" ng-show="isRegLoginFormShown()" ng-click="toggleRegLoginForm()"></div>
<div id="RegLogin" ng-controller="RegLoginController" ng-show="isRegLoginFormShown()"> 
  <span>Please log in</span>
  <br />
  <form>
    <input type="text" name="username" value="username" 
      onfocus="this.value = this.value=='username'?'':this.value;" 
      onblur="this.value = this.value==''?'username':this.value;">
      <br>
    <input type="password" name="password" value="password" 
      onfocus="this.value = this.value=='password'?'':this.value;" 
      onblur="this.value = this.value==''?'password':this.value;">
    <br>
    <input type="button" name="login" value="Login">
  </form>
  <a href="" ng-click="switchToRegistration()">{{registrationText}}</a>
</div>
```

`$scope.registrationText` is properly updating, but the data binding isn't getting updated with it. $digest is supposed to be called on the view whenever user interaction occurs correct? Then why does it properly update when I click the registration link but not when clicking the login form again?

Comment: In AngularJS, forms use the [ng-model directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) to bind to scope variables. For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Reference - Forms](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms).

Comment: Blur events and focus events are bound to the AngularJS framework with the [ng-blur](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBlur) and [ng-focus](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngFocus) directives.

Comment: AngularJS modifies the normal JavaScript flow by providing its own event processing loop. This splits the JavaScript into classical and AngularJS execution context. Only operations which are applied in the AngularJS execution context will benefit from AngularJS data-binding, exception handling, property watching, etc... For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - Integration with the browser event loop](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#integration-with-the-browser-event-loop).